# Parsing datetime with Z and T in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm currently using an API that's returning a timestamp in a weird format that I'm struggling to parse into a unix timestamp for my database, the result I'm receiving is:

```
"date": "20190412T131518.000Z",
```

I've tried using:

```
var date = new Date(array.date);
console.log(date.parse);
```

Which just returns `NaN` so I'm unsure where to go with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add some dashes and colons.

> ```
> 20190412T131518.000Z     // input
> 2019-04-12T13:15:18.000Z // needed format
> ```

It looks like, that [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) does not fully accept date string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. It respects only  a [version](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) from the standard in the form

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

```js
var string = "20190412T131518.000Z",
    date = new Date(string.replace(/(....)(..)(.....)(..)(.*)/, '$1-$2-$3:$4:$5'));

console.log(date);
```

Comment: It always seems odd to me to parse a string to generate another string that is then parsed by the built–in parser. Why not parse it once and give the values directly to the Date constructor?

Comment: @RobG, then it needs a bit more parsing. actually you get another iso compliant string.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see how "*it needs a bit more parsing*" or why an ISO 8601 compliant string is needed. Having split the string into the relevant parts, a suitable timestamp can be generated directly from *Date.UTC* with no further parsing.

Comment: that is even more worst. month with adjustment is even more error prone than a replacement and a human readable result.

Answer (score 4):

You can parse from the string to the `Date` object as below:

```js
let rawDate = "20190412T131518.000Z";
let myDate = new Date(Date.UTC(
  rawDate.substr(0, 4),
  rawDate.substr(4, 2),
  rawDate.substr(6, 2),
  rawDate.substr(9, 2),
  rawDate.substr(11, 2),
  rawDate.substr(13, 2)
));

console.log(myDate);
```